# We should get rid of the stage-magic tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [stage-magic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stage-magic) tag has a problem. All of the questions tagged with it, except for one question ([Is it reasonable to assume that volunteers in stage-magic shows are aides?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/145/is-it-reasonable-to-assume-that-volunteers-in-stage-magic-shows-are-aides)), ask about whether a piece of performance art is real or a trick. The problem with it is that by tagging it with the tag [stage-magic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stage-magic), you are already giving an answer that it's fake - Both from the description of the tag:

> ..audiences are entertained by staged tricks or illusions of seemingly impossible or supernatural feats using natural means.

and the common understanding that modern magicians are using tricks.

Beyond the current questions tagged, I also feel that most questions tagged with it will be of this sort: How do Shaolin Monks do this and that, can the Magnetic man really stick irons to himself, can Uri Geller read minds, did David Blane hold his breath for 17 minutes and so on.

A. We shouldn't presume that what we see is trickery, this is not our site's way.

B. Sometimes it's just that, a person who has trained all their life to master a skill or an art.

I think that a more appropriate tag would be "Performance" or "Performance-Arts" to differentiate those acts from people who claim to have and use those powers for non-entertainment purposes. A performance tag would be neutral and not assuming one answer, and it would help differentiate people who claim to have powers and just show them off for entertainment value, or people who claim they have power and use it for other means.

Comment: +1 for seeing a problem. Not convinced yet by the solution.

Comment: Related: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/are-magic-tricks-in-scope?rq=1

Comment: Burination requests; [needs more puns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257542/171697). (May I suggest "stage-magic needs the disappearing act". or "Lets perform the vanishing act on stage-magic")

Comment: @Jamiec "Should [stage-magic] exit, stage right?"